# Facebook Access Token expires ONLY on chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, access-token

I don't understand why my app loose the access token only when I navigate with Chrome (in Firefox the access token stay for days).

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'XXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
'fileUpload' => false,
'cookie'=>true
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$userfb = $facebook->getUser();

try {

$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?access_token='.$accessToken);
$userfb_id=$userfb;

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
$userfb=0;

}   

if(!$userfb) {

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
array(
'scope'         => 'email,publish_actions',
'redirect_uri'  => 'https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX/',
)
);

echo '<script> top.location.href="'. $url .'"; </script>';

}
```

In Chrome, after one hour from the start I have the "Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." error

Than, every 10-15 minutes I have the same error.

But, with Firefox, everything is perfect, and I can use my app for hours without access token error.

Any help?

Comment: A normal access token will only be valid for 1-2 hours in any case. Perhaps you need to implement some sort of access token refreshing after a certain period of time. [Reference from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

Comment: Yes I know that, but why in firefox I opened my app three days ago and it's still perfectly functioning without any token error???

Comment: IF that is the case the problem might be in Firefox :P Sounds to me like you are experiencing a bug at the Facebook level. Perhaps you should look at their [bug system](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) for other users with the same problem.

Comment: Normally there is no need with the PHP SDK to pass the access token manually, the SDK takes care of that internally. And I think you might be misinterpreting your problem here – and that the access token does not actually expire earlier, but that you simple _don’t have one_ any more. Most likely a problem with (session) cookies, so check your cookie settings and debug what cookie your browser has stored at this point.